# Цель работы –/:

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно?

1. Цель работы – доказать, что изучeние немецкого языка посредством мультфильмов довольно-таки возможно.
2. Цель работы: доказать, что изучeние немецкого языка посредством мультфильмов довольно-таки возможно.

Comment: Мне кажется, правильно поставить тире. Хотя оба варианта возможны в теории

Comment: Какое ещё изучание, выдумщик?))

Comment: Я случайно, случайно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) ***Цель работы:** доказать, что изучение немецкого языка посредством мультфильмов довольно-таки возможно.*

Обозначение цели научной работы (аннотация, краткая характеристика статьи **перед основным текстом**).

(2) ***Цель работы** – доказать, что изучение немецкого языка посредством мультфильмов довольно-таки возможно.*

Обозначение цели работы в **самом тексте** статьи.

**[Розенталь, пункт 4](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103#pp103)**

**Тема доклада** — «Современные молодые художники» (тире между подлежащим и сказуемым при отсутствии связки);

**Тема урока:** «Бессоюзное сложное предложение» (запись на доске в виде заголовка, в котором вторая часть поясняет первую; между ними ставится двоеточие).

Answer (score -1):

Никакого ни тире, ни двоеточия не нужно:

Цель работы доказать... - это утверждение.

Запятая будет нужна, если это сложносочиненное.

А двоеточие ставится, когда уже *цель* разбивается на *задачи*. Для этого нужно: 1) оценить уровень произношения в группах детей которые смотрели мультики, а не только читали учебники и слушали записи, и тех, кто использовал только текстовые материалы и аудиоматериалы для изучении; 2) и тп.

> *Основная цель работы* по заявленному проекту расчет баланса рудного и россыпного золота в Ат-Юрях-Штурмовском узле Яно-Колымского золотоносного пояса. Научный отчет (2004)

> *Цель работы* состояла в том, чтобы обнаружить газодвижущую силу для
> контакта жидких тел, точнее, таких пар, как вода — керосин и вода —
> растительное масло. Игорь Силкин. Эффект резонанса // «Наука в России», 2012

Тирешечка нужна при кривом согласовании:

> *Цель работы* — разработка систем асинхронного маскирования РС на основе алгоритма Хургина-Яковлева.

То есть "цель работы разработать..." - ну тут уже проблемы очевидно), да и вообще это не цель, очевидно, а задача. Цель работы создать системы асинхронного маскирования... а задачи - разработать, затем внедрить и тп.

По аналогии: Цель работы – доказа**тельство** возможности изучения языка посредством мультфильмов.

*довольно-таки* - стилистика ни к чёрту, как обычно у котов.

Цель работы доказать возможность изучение (немецкого) языка посредством просмотра мультфильмов, а именно: расширение словарного запаса изучающего, улучшение произношения, запоминания языковых шаблонов.. и тп.

"А именно:" - это перечисление задач, для достижения цели.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148963/discussion-on-answer-by----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.